# WPF datagrid: How to set specifc setter in C# in stead of XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

**EDIT** Due to lack of sleep I wrote function where I meant converter-class. Changed that below to make it more clear what is going on.

I've got a WPF datagrid where I use a C# <del>function</del> converter-class *SetBrushColor* to set the background brush on some cells in a specific column. (Color used depends on the value in the cell.)
This is working as intended. Small extract of the relevant part of the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SetBrushColor x:Key="SetBrushColor"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{MyData}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{MyData, Converter {StaticResource SetBrushColor}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

I'm now trying to re-use that same C# <del>function</del> converter-class to do the same for a new version of the datagrid that is programmatically generated. The number of columns is variable now and the column with the colored cells shifts around.

I can dynamically add the columns and data-rows without any problems to the grid. (In the XAML I just removed the DataGridTextColumn specifications from the grid so I start with an empty one.)

Where I get in trouble is the point where I need to add the Setter to the ElementStyle property of the column. I can't figure out how to write the corresponding statement in the binding part.
In my C# code I've got now:

```
...
DataGridTextColumn myCol = new DataGridTextColumn();
myCol.Header = "My Special Column";
myCol.Width = 200;
Style colStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
colStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, new Binding( <<<what goes here ?>>> )));
myCol.ElementStyle = colStyle;
myCol.Binding = new Binding("MyData");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(myCol);
...
```

I'm pretty new to C# and even less experienced with WPF, but so far I have been able to figure out most things.
But on this one I need a little guidance how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
colStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, new Binding("MyData"){ Converter = new SetBrushColor() }));
```

Comment: I will try 1st thing tomorrow, when I'm back in the office. Could be my lack of C# experience, but using my SetBrushColor() function with "new" like that looks very wrong to me.

Comment: SetBrushColor is a converter class, isn't it? It is not a method.

Comment: Just tested and it works fine. If I understand this correctly I can also remove the WindowsResources section from the XAML now as it isn't needed anymore ?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the SetBrushColor  resource from <Window.Resources>.